# How to read HDF table from pandas?

Tags: python, io, pandas, hdf5

I have an `my_file.h5` file that, presumably, contains data in HDF5 format (PyTables). I try to read this file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore('my_file.h5')
```

Then I try to use the `store` object:

```
print store
```

As a result I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 133, in __repr__
    kind = v._v_attrs.pandas_type
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/attributeset.py", line 302, in __getattr__
    (name, self._v__nodePath)
AttributeError: Attribute 'pandas_type' does not exist in node: '/data'
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Can the problem be caused by the fact that my `*.h5` is not really what I think it is (not data in hdf5 format)?

Answer (score 3):

In your `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/io/pytables.py`, line 133

```
kind = v._v_attrs.pandas_type
```

In my `pytables.py` I see

```
kind = getattr(n._v_attrs,'pandas_type',None)
```

By using `getattr`, if there is no `pandas_type` attribute, then `kind` is set to `None`. I'm guessing my version of Pandas

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd

In [8]: pd.__version__
Out[8]: '0.10.0'
```

is newer than yours. If so, the fix is to upgrade your `pandas`.

Comment: you will need at least 0.10.1 (and 0.11 is out now), to read a non-pandas created HDF5 table, you can do ``ptdump -avd file.h5`` to inspect it btw

Answer (score 2):

I had a h5 table.   Made with pytables independent of pandas and needed to turn it into a list of tuples then import it to a df.    This woked nice because it allows me to make use of my pytables index to run a "where" on the input.  This saves me reading all the rows.